# Why is sudo required when using pip to install libraries into a virtualenv on an AWS EMR master node?

Tags: python, linux, pip, amazon-emr

I am trying to use pip to install libraries into a Python virtualenv, which resides on an AWS EMR master node.  For some reason, sudo pip works fine, but non-sudo pip *silently* fails.

Some background:

- I am launching an EMR cluster with version emr-5.19.0.
- I am SSHing into the master node, which uses Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03.
- By default, this OS has both Python 2.7 and 3.4 installed.
- I created a new virtualenv, based on the already-installed Python 3.4.
- I activated my new virtualenv, and verified that all paths point to my venv installation (*not* to the global Python installation), e.g. `which python`, `which pip` all look correct.

So, I create and activate my virtualenv as follows:

```
cd /home/ec2-user/my_app
virtualenv --python=python3.4 venv
source venv/bin/activate
```

This works.  Next, I try to install a sample library as follows:

```
pip install numpy
```

The output is:

```
Collecting numpy
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.16.0
```

However, despite the output claiming success, `import numpy` produces an import error, and numpy doesn't show up in `pip list` or `pip freeze`.  I have even drilled into `path/to/venv/lib/python3.4/dist-packages` and verified no `numpy` directory gets created.

Sadly, this *does* work:

```
sudo path/to/venv/bin/pip install numpy
```

The problem is: I don't want to use sudo, because that would defy [best practices](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802544/is-sudo-pip-install-still-a-broken-practice).  However, it seems like most people are using sudo for this task (examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31525012/how-to-bootstrap-installation-of-python-modules-on-amazon-emr) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168663/how-to-install-custom-packages-on-amazon-emr-bootstrap-action-in-code)), so perhaps this is just a requirement in an EMR environment?

Note:  This issue only happens for *some* libraries.  For instance, pyspark and geocoder install fine, but numpy and pandas silently fail.

Comment: You need to show how you are running the code that imports numpy. Most probably, you are not doing so inside the virtualenv where you installed it.

Comment: It may depend on the numpy libs being linked from lower system levels.

Comment: python -m venv <venvname> may be an updated version vs standalone virtualenv

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I am confident my code was running 'inside' my venv, because I launched an interactive Python shell by calling the venv binary directly.  From there, I simply tried `import numpy`, `import pyspark`, etc.  FYI, I ended up solving this issue.  Please see my answer posted below.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up figuring this out:  pip was (*sometimes*, but not always) placing modules in a particular directory that wasn't on the Python path!  This appears to be a [known bug](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4464) between Amazon Linux and pip.

For instance, numpy was getting placed at:

```
path/to/venv/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/numpy
```

However, pyspark was getting placed at:

```
path/to/venv/lib64/python3.4/dist-packages/pyspark
```

The latter directory is on the Python path, but the former was not.  This is why `import pyspark` worked, but `import numpy` did not.  We can force pip to install libraries into the appropriate directory as follows:

```
pip install numpy --target='/path/to/venv/lib/python3.4/dist-packages'
```

The command above solves my issue.